# Show that $f(x) = \mathbb{E} e^{(-\vert Y - x\vert)}$ is continuous on the real line, where $Y$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm having a hard time getting started with this one. Any hints?

Show that $f(x) = \mathbb{E} e^{(-\vert Y - x\vert)}$ is continuous on the real line, where $Y$ is a random variable.

Attempt:

Let $x_n\rightarrow x \in \mathbb{R} $ be arbitrary. We need to show that:

$$\lim_{x_n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{x_n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}e^{-\vert Y - x_n\vert} =\mathbb{E}e^{-\vert Y - x\vert} = f(x) $$

Since $e^{-\vert Y - x_n\vert}$ is bounded above by $1$ and nonnegative for every n, we have

$$\lvert e^{-\vert Y - x_n\vert}\rvert\leq 1 \text{       } \forall n,$$

Thus, by the Dominated Convergence, we have:

$$\lim_{x_n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}e^{-\vert Y - x_n\vert}= \mathbb{E}\lim_{x_n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}e^{-\vert Y - x_n\vert} = \mathbb{E}e^{-\vert Y - x\vert}$$

With the last equality holding by continuity of the exponential function.

Comment: Hint: Can you write down a formula for the expected value of a function of a random variable?

Comment: Dominayed convergente theorem cbined with the continuity of the function inside the expectation.

Comment: Thanks @Kolmo. Does this look right (edited)?

Comment: Looks good to me. Correct a bit the notation. You made some typos.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\big|e^{-|y-x_1|} - e^{-|y-x_2|}\big| \le |x_1 - x_2|$.